# Cycles in oribifolds

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Suppose we have a compact, orientable, $n$-dimensional orbifold $X$, where $n \geq 3$. Suppose that there is a single isolated orbifold point $p_{0} \in X$, with a neighbourhood homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n} /\{\pm 1\}$, i.e. the cone over $\mathbb{RP}^{n-1}$. In particular $X$ has a single orbifold point with order $2$.

In what follows when I refer to homology, I mean just the singular homology of the underlying topological space of $X$. I think that the following statement should be true and I would like to ask for a proof or a reference for it.

**Question:** Suppose we have a integral cycle $C \in C_{d}(X,\mathbb{Z})$ in $X$ and $0 < d < \dim(X)$. Then $[2C]$ is represented by a cycle which is (set-theoretically) disjoint from $p_{0} \in X$.

Comment: Yes, this works, just use the M-V sequence and the fact that $H_*(RP^{n-1})$ is 2-torsion, apart from degrees $0$ and $n-1$.

Comment: Thanks +1, that helps a lot!

Comment: If you don't mind I am going to write up the details in an answer, although if you decide to write an answer I will accept that version.

Comment: Sure, that's why I gave the hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the details of Moishe Kohan's nice solution. We will need the the following fact:

**Fact:** Let $m>0$ be an integer, for $0<i<m$ for any $\alpha \in H_{i}(\mathbb{RP}^{m},\mathbb{Z})$ satisfies $2 \alpha =0$.

Let $U$ be a small neighbourhood of the orbifold point, homeomorphic the cone on $\mathbb{RP}^{n-1}$, in particular $U$ is contractible. Let $V$ be a small neighbourhood of $X \setminus U$, so that $U \cap V$ is homeomorphic to $(0,1) \times \mathbb{RP}^{n-1}$, in particular it is homotopy equivelant to $\mathbb{RP}^{n-1}$. Let fix $0<d<\dim(X)$ and consider the following part of the MV sequence ascosiated to $(X,U,V)$. All homology group are taken with integral coeeffients, we use reduced homology to ensure the case $d=1$ works out.

$$\ldots \rightarrow H_{d}(U) \oplus H_{d}(V) \rightarrow H_{d}(X) \rightarrow H_{d-1}(U \cap V) \rightarrow \ldots $$

Consider $\beta \in H_{d}(X)$, then by the Fact, the image of $2\beta$ in $H_{d-1}(U \cap V)$ is zero, hence $2\beta$ is in the image of $H_{d}(U) \oplus H_{d}(V)$. The inclusion of any cycle in $V$ is clearly disjoint from the orbifold point. Any cycle contained in $U$ can also be made disjoint because $U$ is contractible.  Hence, the class $2\beta$ is represented by a cycle disjoint from the orbifold point.